# Installing mysql in debian10

Tags: debian, mysql

I am new in debian and I'm trying to install mysql, But when I do these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

then this error will come up :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Plus when I use the command sudo apt-get update this error comes up :

```
Ign:8 https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages buster InRelease
Ign:9 https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-tools/binary-i386/Packages buster InRelease
Err:10 https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-8.0/binary-amd64/Packages buster Release
  Redirection from https to 'http://www.mysql.com/downloads/embargo.html' is forbidden [IP: 2.20.149.25 443]
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu eoan InRelease                      
Err:12 https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/mysql-tools/binary-i386/Packages buster Release
  Redirection from https to 'http://www.mysql.com/downloads/embargo.html' is forbidden [IP: 2.20.149.25 443]
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu eoan Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian there's no MySql in the standard repositories. There's the equivalent of it named MariaDB with the corresponding package `mariadb-server`. As for the errors, you must have followed (I guess) some tutorial and introduced some mess in the repositories, which you most likely should clean up now. I'd try to find out what exactly has been added to the repository lists, what's been installed, and what should be removed now. You can get this info from your shell history and possibly the package management logs.

To give a more comprehensive answer, you might want to stick to MySql and install it from their installers, but make sure you really want to. This is a tougher way in comparison to the Debian's default MariaDB.

Comment: How can I access to shell history and package manager logs ?

Comment: @amirhosein 1. Try the command `history`. 2. Check `/var/log/apt` and `/var/log/dpkg`.

Comment: I think i removed some packages by using `sudo apt --fix-broken install` command. How can I find out which packages are lust to install them again?

Comment: @amirhosein If your Debian is next to new with no important data nor configurations and you can install a new one, you might think of reinstalling it... (Possibly after a backup too in case there's anything to back up.)

Comment: I am new in linux and I have a project with a deadline that doesn't let me do that.
plus I live in Iran and because of that I am banned from so many servers and services and I can't find a vpn connection that solve these issues.

Comment: @amirhosein You don't seem to know what's going on there with the packages and repositories... I don't want to give you misleading hints as it might get you in even worse troubles. If you're pressed for time and need a quick fix, possibly you might build a new Debian with MariaDB on a virtual machine, if this is not too difficult...

Comment: Thank you @Tomasz I will do that

Comment: A VM should work, but just `apt-get remove` (or `apt-get purge`) on all mysql server and client packages should clean up the mess.  Remove all repo.mysql entries from sources.list and then install mariadb.   You can list all installed mysql packages with `dpkg -l 'mysql*' | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}'`.    or purge them all with `apt-get purge $(dpkg -l 'mysql*' | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}')`.

Comment: @amirhosein See cas' comment above.